# Response from server NSDate give me always - 8 hrs

Tags: iphone, nsdate

My server server side response one value as Date value. 
But when i get from client side (iPhone) is always - 8 hrs.

Eg. Server response 23-May-2013

But client side (iPhone) got 22-May-2013 16:00:00

What should I do. Because our Android project also use same web-service and they got it properly.

I don't know what is the problem. There have no formatting. just use NSLog for response value.

Comment: Here we go again. Can we please add the NSLog timezone issue as a FAQ on the 'ask a question' page?

Comment: What is your code?
Without code how can we help you??

Comment: @Chan, May be helpful..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621330/nsdateformatter-not-working-to-set-settimezone

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Locale for the NSDate

```
 NSLocale *locale_us = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateformatter setLocale:locale_us];
```

Also, setting the Time Zone can help too.

Answer (score 0):

Of corse they have a formatting. The same point in time (the same NSDate) could look different when shown in different time zones.

NSLog uses GMT, perhaps you could add some sample code to you question and tell us in which time zone you live in?

See also [WWDC 2011 Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) 117: Performing Calendar Calculations. *(Apple Developer Account required)*

Comment: Currently we are trying from Singapore, But at the same time some of the team are trying in India. 
Singapore side transaction was show filter by date, But India side they cannot see any transaction.
And both side are testing same module.
I don't know which code need to show. 
eg.For singapore . they got response 22-May-2013 16:00:00 then we convert base on GTM timezone, So they got 23-May-2013.

but india side, They also got 22-May-2013 16:00:00 then we convert base on time zone, but india GTM time was +5:30.So 22-May-2013 16:00:00 + 5:30 is still 22-May-2012 21:30:00. So nothing shown :(