# iOS NSDateFormatter returns wrong date

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

`dbVoiceDate` is wrong why?

I tried a lot!

```
NSDateFormatter *formatterVoice = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatterVoice.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
dbVoiceDate = [formatterVoice dateFromString:dbDateStr];
```

**Getting response:**

Printing description of dbDateStr:

```
03-Oct-2016 10:43:59
```

Printing description of `self->dbVoiceDate`:

```
2016-10-03 05:02:16 +0000
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Timezone is the issue, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621330/nsdateformatter-not-working-to-set-settimezone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442706/nsdateformatter-and-time-zone-issue

Comment: What kind of date you wont tell me .. then i give you perfect answer .

Comment: TimeZone issue, no? The small differences on the seconds part is due to something else, and it seems that your date may need `HH` instead of `hh` for the hours, because it doesn't have AM or PM explicitly written.$

Comment: There's a gazillion other posts telling you the you need to lear about time zones.

Answer (score 1):

format it like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

//then do your coding.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
NSString *dateString = @"Thu Oct 3 10:34:58 +0000 2016";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *finalDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", finalDateStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code:

```
+(NSString*)getDateWithMonthSpelling:(NSString*)dateStr
{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
    NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy";
    NSString*myDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
    return myDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the timezone. If it is in GMT set timezone to GMT, like this:

```
[youDateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Else you can use your local timezone like this:

```
[youDateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```